# android: DatePicker background on KindleFire HD

Tags: android, datepicker, kindle-fire

I tryed to use DatePicker dialog on Kindle. But Edit fields without the background! How I can to fix it (standard-way)? You can check it in emulator. I use Android 2.2 for building application.

[image]

Comment: No idea. Might try and change your theme for the activity from manifest.

Comment: I have no ideas too... This is my custom theme, but DatePicker - standard component... In other devices this dialog works fine.

Comment: which version of the Kindle Fire are you using? Gingerbread or ICS based?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I was able to solve it by calling the DatePickerDialog's setInverseBackgroundForced and passing in true.